# is ubuntu an x11 display itself?

Tags: 12.04, xorg

is using an ubuntu eventually using an x11 display?

I see that with `env | grep DISPLAY` I get `DISPLAY=:0.0`

so dose this mean that ubuntu itself is another extension of x11?

Comment: What do you mean by an `extension of x11`?

Comment: @Oli i mean, X11 is the stuff that allows GUI to users right? Ubuntu is also something that has GUI. Then is Ubuntu's GUI based on X11?

Comment: Ubuntu is a *linux* distribution based on *debian/gnome* and provides *unity* desktop environment. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_environment

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Ubuntu uses X and Unity and all Ubuntu's other desktop environments sit on top it...

But I'm not sure I'd ever call them "extensions". They're just clients.

---

There are more modern alternatives being developed:

- Mir by Canonical, and
- Wayland by (seemingly) everybody else

While these might one day succeed at removing X from the default, it seems unlikely that X will be completely removed for a very long time because there will be things that just aren't happy without X (even if that means through a layer like XMir).

Comment: sorry if I've used the word 'extensions' I just didn't know what I was talking about..

Comment: by the way in the comment above, @kenn mentioned that ubuntu is based on unity and nothing related to X. But you said that _Ubuntu uses X_ so which one of you is right?

Comment: @kwagjj I'm always right... But seriously, Unity is an application/plugin for Compiz (a compositor) which is an application which sits on top of X. We're both right. As I say in my answer, all the current official desktops (whatever their respective compositors) sit on top of X.

Comment: okay~ I believe you. I'm a newbie with linux so I don't understand your answer fully but I get the point: Ubuntu sits on top of X :) thanks!

Comment: @kwagjj
I noticed your confusion and tried to explain that Ubuntu was rather related to desktop environments. Most of the desktop environments are on top of X11 server. Oli is a master here :) His answer is always precious. For info for X11   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System